# 'There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout' for webchat

Tags: azure-bot-service

When I Test in Webchat it displays couldn't send retry. Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

[webchaterror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygafA.png)

Comment: That error can mean many things. If you can provide you `appId`, I can research this quite a bit further. What method did you use to deploy/publish your bot? Does your deployed `.bot` file have a "production" endpoint listed?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?